# Babel-CLI set config value correctly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-cli

I am trying to add a build command that uses babel CLI to transpile my ES6. I am having difficult pointing it correctly to babelrc.

The file structure is roughly as follows:

```
root
    src
        index.js
        ...
    .babelrc
    .package.json
```

In my package.json, I originally tried the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel --out-dir dist src",
    ...
  },
```

But this gave an error because of the array destructuring notation I have used in my code. I think this is because it is not picking up my `.babelrc` file. Using

`babel --presets=@babel/preset-env --out-dir dist src`

instead fixes this problem. But I would rather I didn't have to specify plugins etc. here and rely on the `.babelrc` file instead.

From reading [this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5297), I get the impression babel looks for a config file in `src` rather than `root` . Looking at [the documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#custom-config-path) it seems there is an option for specifying a config file, but I can't quite get it to work correctly. My attempt:

```
babel --config-file .babelrc --out-dir dist src
```

Comment: Btw, shouldn't the command be `babel src --out-dir dist`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `./node_modules/.bin/babel` in place of `babel`.

Worked for me this week.

Check point 3 in the overview from babel-cli
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage

> 3. And running this command to compile all your code from the src directory to lib:
>
> `./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib`
>
> You can use the npm package runner that comes with npm@5.2.0 to shorten that command by replacing `./node_modules/.bin/babel` with `npx babel`

Answer (score 0):

For Babel version 7.x, it looks for project-wide configuration in the file with name like this - `babel.config.{json|js|cjs|mjs}`. Check the documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

In my end,

> npx babel  src/ -d lib/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Babel should already pick up the `.babelrc` file automatically. If you want to add that preset, you should specify

```
{
  // ... more .babelrc up here
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  // ... more .babelrc down here
}
```

in your `.babelrc` file.

But babel will automatically search for the closest `.babelrc` file in the directory starting at the entry file and working its way upwards (specified [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babelrc) at the bottom).

Comment: That preset is already in my `.babelrc` file. That's what I want it to pick up, but it is not doing so at the moment.

Comment: webpack, is picking it up from the `.babelrc` file. But babel-cli isn't for some reason.